# Login to website using jsoup in android returning login page instead of home page

Tags: android, jsoup

I have used all the input tags fields name from source and tried all possible ways using jSoup to connect but each time the output html page showing in log.e is the same login page.

```
protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
    try {

  Connection.Response loginForm = Jsoup.connect("http://adsl.yemen.net.ye/en/login.aspx")
              //  .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36")
                .method(Connection.Method.GET)
                .execute();
        loginForm= Jsoup.connect("http://adsl.yemen.net.ye/en/login.aspx")
                .data("ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$loginframe$UserName", "MASALAHI2010")
                .data("ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$loginframe$Password", "MAMAM")
               // .data("ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$loginframe$RememberMe","true")
                .data("ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$loginframe$LoginButton", "Sign In")
                .data("__LASTFOCUS", "")
                .data("__EVENTTARGET", "")
                .data("__EVENTARGUMENT","")
                .data("__VIEWSTATE","/wEPDwULLTE4NzkxODYxNTIPZBYCZg9kFgICAw9kFgQCAQ9kFgQCAw8PFgIeB1Zpc2libGVoZGQCBQ8PFgIfAGhkZAIDD2QWCAIBDzwrAAoBAA8WAh4IVXNlck5hbWUFDE1BU0FMQUhJMjAxMGQWAmYPZBYEAgMPDxYGHghSZWFkT25seWceBFRleHQFDE1BU0FMQUhJMjAxMB4HRW5hYmxlZGhkZAIPDxAPFgIeB0NoZWNrZWRoZGRkZAIFDw8WAh8AaGRkAgcPDxYCHwBoZGQCCQ8PFgIfAGhkFgICBQ8PFgIfBGhkZBgBBR5fX0NvbnRyb2xzUmVxdWlyZVBvc3RCYWNrS2V5X18WAQUvY3RsMDAkQ29udGVudFBsYWNlSG9sZGVyMSRsb2dpbmZyYW1lJFJlbWVtYmVyTWU9Ui0fNjQuNhCWW2dC7yFhNqTbNcJm7Q+EVewP9rv8Yg==")
                .data("__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR","EE376E4E")
                .data("__EVENTVALIDATION","/wEWBQKP+oCbCALfq6j2AQKR/OC4DgKj1+LbCwLs5ZY/pEGu3qyHck5jsPKXcvY2hzZwLeCSbXeQ4TprZKrhv7E=")
                .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36")
                .cookies(loginForm.cookies())



                .method(Connection.Method.POST)
                .execute();

        Document homePage = Jsoup.connect("http://adsl.yemen.net.ye/en/user_main.aspx")
                .cookies(loginForm.cookies())
                .get();




        Log.e("test", homePage.html());

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're almost there, just a few minor things:

You see the login form data that you need to send other than username and password (e.g. `__VIEWSTATE`, `__EVENTVALIDATION` and more)? Those need to be retrieved **dynamically**. I believe they are unique values sent to you when you first go to the login form page.

So what you need to do is, instead of `POST`ing fixed values, you need to parse them from the first `loginForm` you received, just like you set the cookies from the first login form.

For more details I've written up a comprehensive tutorial on how to login to websites using Jsoup [here](http://joelmin.blogspot.com.au/2016/04/how-to-login-to-website-using-jsoup-java_4.html), I believe it will help you a lot.

Comment: I have followed the same tutorial liknk you have sent me . could you plz explain By dynamically tou mean the way you retrieved that authenticity token ?IF yes then wat that #login in the syntax of that retrieval?

Comment: I have tried dynamic attribute value as well but it still returning same login page

Answer (score 0):

Jsoup.connect(URL)  .method(Method.GET)
                    .followRedirects(false) // <-- did the trick
                    .cookie(SESSION_KEY, sessionId)
                    .execute();